# Extracting specific rows of grouped items conditionally in R

Tags: r

I have the dataset below which is representative of a much larger dataset I am working with.  The dataset below has 3 columns: a 'weight','feed',and 'flag'.  Weight is a numerical value, feed is a factor variable, and flag is my indicator variable.  Flag takes on a  value of 0,1, or 2 (which will ultimately be random, but please use values provided below).

For what factor category in the 'feed' field, I want to examine the 'flag' field.  If the 'flag' value = 2 & for the first occurrence of that value of 2 then I want to take the next 2 consecutive rows *for that feed category - if 2 occurs in the last row for a particular feed category, then nothing happens*.

For example, row 2 of the data frame where horsebean =160, the flag value is 2.  I would mark row 3 & 4 since these are the next two rows that follow an occurrence of the value 2 for horsebean.  I would need to be careful though in the event that horsebean flag value of 2 didn't occur until row 9 or 10 - I wouldn't want to accidentally select rows from linseed.

Ideally a 4th column is created with some sort of flag indicating they were the rows that followed a flag value of 2.

If anyone could help me formulate or attack this problem I would be eternally grateful.

```
df =    structure(list(weight = c(179, 160, 136, 227, 217, 168, 108, 
  124, 143, 140, 309, 229, 181, 141, 260, 203, 148, 169, 213, 257, 
  244, 271, 243, 230, 248, 327, 329, 250, 193, 271, 316, 267, 199, 
 171, 158, 248, 423, 340, 392, 339, 341, 226, 320, 295, 334, 322, 
 297, 318, 325, 257, 303, 315, 380, 153, 263, 242, 206, 344, 258, 
368, 390, 379, 260, 404, 318, 352, 359, 216, 222, 283, 332), 
feed = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("casein", "horsebean", "linseed", "meatmeal", 
"soybean", "sunflower"), class = "factor"), flag = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("weight", "feed", 
 "flag"), row.names = c(NA, -71L), class = "data.frame")
```

Also suppose that the flag values are randomly generated and the flag value of 2 may or may not appear for each grouped value.  For example if

```
  df$flag = sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20), replace=T, size=nrow(df))
```

Comment: What happens if 2 would occur on row 9? Would want to select only one row afterwords?

Comment: Yes - you want to select the following 1-2 rows after flag value =2 for the group that you are examining.  So you need to control for staying within the correct 'feed' category.  So in your example, yes just one more row rather than two since selecting a 2nd row would exit you into the 'linseed' feed.

Comment: Not sure who is flagging this as "OT because why is my code isn't working"... There is no code that not working here. I think that maybe people are flagging this because you didn't show your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
indx <- setDT(df)[, .I[match(2, flag) + seq_len(2)], by = feed]$V1
df[indx, flag2 := 1][]
#     weight      feed flag flag2
#  1:    179 horsebean    1    NA
#  2:    160 horsebean    2    NA
#  3:    136 horsebean    2     1
#  4:    227 horsebean    2     1
#  5:    217 horsebean    2    NA
#  6:    168 horsebean    0    NA
#  7:    108 horsebean    1    NA
#  8:    124 horsebean    1    NA
#  9:    143 horsebean    1    NA
# 10:    140 horsebean    0    NA
# ...
```

Why this will work? Because we use `match` in order to match the *first* `2` within `.I` (index) within each group. Thus if the index exceeds the size of a certain group it will return `NA`. Eventually `index` is just the indexes of the rows we want to select. Thus while sub-setting by this index, we are assigning a new flag which will tell us which rows we want.

For example, If you want to select only the rows within `flag2`, simply use `na.omit` by the `flag2` column

```
na.omit(df, "flag2")
#     weight      feed flag flag2
#  1:    136 horsebean    2     1
#  2:    227 horsebean    2     1
#  3:    181   linseed    1     1
#  4:    141   linseed    2     1
#  5:    329   soybean    1     1
#  6:    250   soybean    2     1
#  7:    392 sunflower    1     1
#  8:    339 sunflower    1     1
#  9:    257  meatmeal    2     1
# 10:    303  meatmeal    1     1
# 11:    390    casein    2     1
# 12:    379    casein    0     1
```

Comment: wow so fast, thank you very much.  The first part is *exactly* what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi to follow up - how would I need to change your code in the event than a '2' was never found in the 'flag' column?  I currently received errors in the event than a '2' was not found for a particular feed group.

Comment: What errors did you receive? It shouldn't give any error rather just skip that perticular group.

Comment: Yes, it just skips the group, however when you try to append the results to the new column, you receive an error.  For example if you set df$flag=0 before running your code, you would receive an error.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: sorry, maybe this would be easier to understand.  run your code by changing the flag value it looks for from 2 to 99. indx <- setDT(df)[, .I[match(99, flag) + seq_len(2)], by = feed]$V1
df[indx, flag2 := 1][]

Comment: Hmm. I see, you mean that if *never* match anything. So you have such situations?

Comment: If there is at least one `2` in *any* group, this will work perfectly. It is hard to reproduce your problem with the new edit without you add some `set.seed` that will demonstrate when it doesn't work.